# SQL, choosing max date and if two results have a max date, choose the one with the max weight

Tags: sql

```
ID | DATE_I                 | Weight
1  | 10/04/2014 08:13:05  | 10
2  | 02/04/2014 08:13:05  | 15
3  | 08/04/2014 08:13:05  | 10
4  | 13/04/2014 08:13:05  | 12
5  | 13/04/2014 08:13:05  | 10
```

My SQL request request should give me row 4.

```
select id, max(DATE_I)
from MyTable m
where m.Weight > (select m2.Weight from MyTable m2 having max(DATE_I));
```

Comment: What's the matter?
can you explain what you want? and provide a SQLFiddle?

Comment: What do you use mysql,sql server?

Comment: Are you facing any error??

Comment: I see no dates. Just weird strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select y.ID, x.maxdate, x.maxweight
from 
(
  select a.maxdate, Max(b.Weight) as maxweight
  from 
  (
    select max(date_I) as maxdate
    from mytable
  )a 
  inner join mytable b on a.maxdate = b.date_I
  group By a.maxdate
) x inner join mytable y on x.maxweight = y.weight
```

[Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6d31/10)

Answer (score 1):

Order your rows on `DATE_I` and `Weight` descending and get the first row.

Sample code for SQL Server.

```
select top (1) ID, DATE_I, Weight
from mytable
order by DATE_I desc, Weight desc;
```